# Rewrite SQL code to PL/SQL using BULK collection

Tags: sql, performance, plsql, query-optimization, bulkinsert

I am in the beginning of the study how to optimize PL/SQL queries. So, there is in my procedure two `FOR LOOPS` and SQL like `INSERT` statements. And I want to rewrite it using `BULK` collections.

```
CURSOR cur0 IS
    SELECT cal.id, cal.dt, cal.id_period, per.period_name
    FROM xxkkbi_dim_calendar cal, xxkkbi_dim_period per
    WHERE (cal.dt BETWEEN p_start_date AND p_end_date)
    AND per.id = cal.id_period
    ORDER BY cal.dt;

row0          cur0%ROWTYPE;
l_period_name VARCHAR2(20);
l_id_period   NUMBER;
l_id_date     NUMBER;
l_id_budget   NUMBER;
l_budget_code VARCHAR2(2 CHAR);

BEGIN

FOR row0 IN cur0 LOOP
    l_date        := row0.dt;
    l_period_name := row0.period_name;
    l_id_period   := row0.id_period;
    l_id_date     := row0.id;

    IF TO_CHAR(row0.dt, 'dd.mm') = '01.01' THEN
        l_period_name := 'КОР-' || SUBSTR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(row0.dt, 'YYYY')) - 1, 3);
    END IF;

    FOR row2 IN 
        (SELECT id id_budget, code
        FROM xxkkbi_dim_budget_type
        WHERE id > -1
        AND marker_127 = 'N') 
    LOOP
        l_id_budget   := row2.id_budget;
        l_budget_code := row2.code;

        DELETE FROM fct_5_52
        WHERE id_date = l_id_date
        AND id_budget_type = l_id_budget
        AND id_period = l_id_period;

        INSERT INTO fct_5_52
            (id_date,
            id_period,
            id_gu,
            id_region,
            id_budget_type,
            id_financing_source,
            id_expense_fk,
            id_specific,
            amount_period,
            amount_year)
        SELECT 
            l_id_date AS id_date,
            l_id_period,
            (SELECT gu.id
                FROM xxkkbi_dim_gu gu
                WHERE gu.code = cc.segment6) id_gu,
            (SELECT region.id
                FROM xxkkbi_dim_region region
                WHERE region.code = cc.segment2) id_region,
            (SELECT budget.id
                FROM xxkkbi_dim_budget_type budget
                WHERE budget.code = cc.segment1) id_budget_type,
            (SELECT dfs.id
                FROM xxkkbi_dim_financing_source dfs
                WHERE dfs.code = cc.segment7) id_financing_source,
            (SELECT kbk.id
                FROM xxkkbi_dim_expense_fk kbk
                WHERE kbk.code = cc.segment3) id_expense_fk,
            (SELECT ds.id
                FROM xxkkbi_dim_specific ds
                WHERE ds.code = cc.segment4) id_specific,
            SUM(NVL(jljh.entered, 0)) circle,
            SUM(NVL(bal.begin_balance_dr, 0) - NVL(bal.begin_balance_cr, 0) + NVL(jljh.entered, 0)) saldo
        FROM apps_gl_balances bal
        JOIN apps_gl_code_combinations cc 
        ON (bal.code_combination_id = cc.code_combination_id 
            AND bal.currency_code = 'KZT' 
            AND bal.actual_flag = 'A' 
            AND bal.ledger_id = 2021 
            AND NVL(bal.translated_flag, 'x') IN ('Y', 'N', 'x') 
            AND cc.chart_of_accounts_id = 50408 
            AND cc.template_id IS NULL 
            AND segment5 = '0' 
            AND segment1 between '01' and '03' 
            AND segment3 between '100000000' and '999999999' 
            AND segment4 BETWEEN '000111' AND'000999' 
            AND bal.period_name = l_period_name 
            AND (
                    (NVL(bal.period_net_dr, 0) - NVL(bal.period_net_cr, 0)) != 0 OR
                    (NVL(bal.begin_balance_dr, 0) - NVL(bal.begin_balance_cr, 0)) != 0
                )
            )
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (SELECT 
                jl.code_combination_id,
                SUM(NVL(jl.entered_dr, 0) - NVL(jl.entered_cr, 0)) entered
            FROM 
                gl_gl_je_lines jl, 
                gl_gl_je_headers jh
            WHERE jl.period_name = l_period_name
            AND jl.effective_date <= l_date
            AND jh.je_header_id = jl.je_header_id
            AND jh.period_name = jl.period_name
            AND jh.currency_code = 'KZT'
            AND jh.ledger_id = 2021
            AND jh.actual_flag = 'A'
            GROUP BY jl.code_combination_id) jljh 
        ON 
            (jljh.code_combination_id = cc.code_combination_id)
        GROUP BY 
            cc.segment1,
            cc.segment2,
            cc.segment3,
            cc.segment4,
            cc.segment6,
            cc.segment7;
    COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

And I know that I need to change PL/SQL `NVL` function to SQL `COALESCE` function for reduction context switching.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be executed without loops, in single sql queries - one `INSERT` and one `DELETE`. If your `INSERT` statement operates with big amount of data, you can divide your data on portions and make some lesser `INSERT`s - as I can understand, it is exactly what you did. But using collections can't help you here. Queries with collections could be as effective as pure SQL queries, but not more. If you have performance problem here, you need to search problems in another place. Try to optimize your `SELECT` subqueries. I think problems are here.

Also you need to measure time for execution of one loop. How big it is? If you have many (hundreds or thousands) fast loops (less then 1 second for one loop), try to change size of your data portions.

Also, `NVL` - is SQL function (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm#SQLRF51171), it has not to switch context (as far as I know).

Comment: the query below executes about 5 hours